# Why is my for loop not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
List<WebElement> cells = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));

for(int count = 0;  count <cells.size(); count++) {
    if (cells.get(count).getText().contains("anyname")) {
        cells.get(count).click();
        break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: And to avoid a loop you could use XPath: driver.findElement(By.XPath("//img[contains(text(),'anyname')]"));

Answer (score 0):

one of the main problem in using text - "anyname" is that selenium will confuse which text to be click, so better to use with there id's separately.